# Searching all versions of a file in the undo tree in VIM

Tags: vim, undo

**EDIT:** I have "manually migrated" this question here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2220/1060

---

Is there an easier way to find a particular change in Vim's undo tree than just looking at random old versions of the file one at a time (either using vanilla VIM commands, Gundo, or another plugin)? Ideally, I'd like to enter a search pattern to be matched against all of the diffs shown in the preview pane by Gundo, and then have Gundo show me which versions have diffs that match that search.

This question asks something almost identical, but the asker has accepted an answer that simply recommends Gundo, which, wonderful though it is, doesn't appear to do what I'm asking for: [Search in Vim's undo history](https://superuser.com/q/416658/199803)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim doesn't provide an interface to get previous undo snapshots of a file. You have to (temporarily) restore the change via `:undo {N}`, and perform the search there. When there are many undo branches, this is probably slow, but nothing prevents a plugin like Gundo to implement this.

I would recommend to pitch your idea to Gundo's author, and maybe also to the author of the alternative [undotree.vim - Display your undo history in a graph](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177) plugin.

Comment: Idea pitched, but no response so far. https://bitbucket.org/sjl/gundo.vim/issue/45/search-through-diffs